# C++ error: (eosio contract): Decomposes into 2 elements but only 1 names were provided

Tags: c++, blockchain, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, eos

I get this error when trying to compile the contract.

The specified code:

```
    basic::tradeparams basic::get_defi_trade_data(asset tokens, symbol to){
  sx::registry::defibox_table defi_table( "registry.sx"_n, "registry.sx"_n.value );

  auto rowit = defi_table.find(tokens.symbol.code().raw());
  if(rowit==defi_table.end()) return {};
  name tcontract = rowit->base.get_contract();
  string pair_id;
  for(auto& p: rowit->quotes){
    if(p.first.get_symbol()==to){
      pair_id = p.second; break;
    }                                                         }                                                           if(pair_id=="") return {};

  // get reserves                                             const auto [ reserve_in, reserve_out ] = defibox::get_reserves( stoi(pair_id), tokens.symbol );
  const uint8_t fee = defibox::get_fee();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `EOSLIB_SERIALIZE` to explicitly define fields of the table.

[Documentation page](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.8/group__serialize) about this macro.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34622475)